# Converge roles from controller and methods .NET web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have been facing a problem with the `[Authorize]` attribute. I have 2 roles **Admin** and **User**. I have decorated the controller with the Authorize attribute like `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`. But in the same controller I want some methods to be accessible by both **Admin** and **User**. What I have studied so far is that the `[Authorize]` attribute is additive by default so if I use `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` in the method the user have to be in both **Admin** and **User** role to access the method. But the behaviour I want is that the some methods in the controller should be accessible to both roles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple authorize attributes are additive, but the `roles` property is not.

So, this is additive:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Content("You have to be admin AND user to see this");
    }
}
```

And this is additive too:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Content("You have to be admin AND user to see this");
    }
}
```

But this is not:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Content("You have to be admin OR user to see this");
    }
}
```

Which means that:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Content("You have to be admin to see this. But in other methods of this controller you can be Admin OR User");
    }
}
```